# Intel HAXM not available in VS for MAC

Tags: visual-studio, android-emulator, haxm, vs-community-edition

Can anyone please help me out from below issue coming in VS for Mac.

I'm trying to start default accelerate emulator ship with VS for Mac Community.

It throw error that **Intel HAXM not available** even though its already installed.

[Please go through link to check error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GDFf.png)

Thanks,
Sneh

Comment: Solution: It sounds weird but first start emulator by Tools> Emulator Manager> default accelerate emulator. Once emulator gets start, deploy or run using play button, it will install app without throwing error. It works for me but i couldn't find solution if we directly run the app as ideally this process should trigger emulator first and then deploy app once emulator gets ready.

Answer (score 0):

Download intel xahm for mac and you will be good to go. You can find it on intel's website [here](https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases/download/v7.0.0/haxm-macosx_v7_0_0.zip) or simply google it.

Comment: Thanks @josmelka, I followed same step suggested by you earlier but i missed to start emulator first as mentioned above. Now its working.

Comment: @Chanki, you are welcome. But you should have accepted it as answer if that was a solution

Comment: I don't think barely installing xahm will solve the issue. As suggested by op you still need to manually start the emulator.